# Openfoam - pisoFoam only uses one core

Tags: openfoam

I use openfoam Version 1606+
When I run pisoFoam, in htop (to show CPU Usage) I can see that pisoFoam only uses one core (of course usage 99%). What do I have to modify if I want to use all cores of my CPU?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run `pisoFoam` parallel, roughly the following steps need to be taken:

- Decompose the grid and fields via the command `decomposePar` (assuming you set `system/decomposeParDict` file appropriately).
- Execute `pisoFoam` in parallel mode via this example command: `mpirun -np X pisoFoam -parallel >& logFile(SampiyonCanakkaleDardanel)`, i.e. `X` is the integer number of processors being used. Say you have 4 cores in your workstation, then `X = 4`.

Please note that you do not need to modify anything within `pisoFoam` to perform a parallel task.

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical workflow (after you generate your mesh):

- `checkMesh > log.checkMesh.1 2>&1`
- `decomposePar > log.decomposePar 2>&1`
- `renumberMesh > log.renumberMesh 2>&1`
- `checkMesh > log.checkMesh.2 2>&1`
- `mpiexec -n 5 pisoFoam -parallel > log.pisoFoam 2>&1`
- `reconstructPar`

Notes:

- Tested on v2.4.
- I used 5 as the number of cores in this example. Replace by the number you want. You may want to test using hyperthreading; it may or may not be useful.
- Don't forget the `-parallel` flag.
- `renumberMesh` is useful in cases of large meshes.
- Try to use `functionObjects` as much as you can, as saving time directories can consume a lot of disk space.
- See the OpenFOAM tutorials for examples of all that is mentioned above (e.g. pitzDaily, channel395, damBreak, motorBike etc. etc.)